# Layered Navigation is not coming in sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, layered-navigation

I am using a theme on category page but, no Layered Navigation is coming.

I installed `FME Layered Navigation` which worked on many themes but not in this one.

I commented the active theme folder in template then FME Layered Navigation is coming.

[image: when_layout_commented]

When i comment `layout folder` then it comes as shown in picture.
In page.xml what  must be there to show layered navigation in sidebar.

Its `2coloumn-left`

`If i replace the layout folder with fresh folder then its shown, but i did many changes in this case i have to do those changes again`

Comment: Have you contacted support for the extension? Unless you provide the code it may be difficult for us to know what the problem is.

Comment: @BenCrook Sir this plugin is working fine with this theme in fresh install.

Comment: I made changes in xml as its required,  that time i didn't noticed that layered navigation is blocked. Now i don't know how to make layered navigation visible,  I am not working on this project from last few days, so forget what changes i did.

Comment: And i know its my mistake so there is no point to contact the plugins support, also its a free plugins

Comment: My point is without being able to see how the plugin works or the changes you have made it's hard for us to see what is causing the problem. It could be anything from missing XML, wrong XML, missing template, invalid code, hidden with CSS etc. It's like telling a mechanic your car isn't working, without them seeing your car. They would just be guessing what's wrong unless you provide lots of info.

Comment: Yes you are right , even i dont know what to ask . as i have no idea . so i am checking files as per the last modified date and comparing it to default fresh files , Hope it help me.

Comment: You could run a diff between the original files and the current files, this will tell you what is different and it may help you or give you some more information to add to this question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Magento native Layered Navigation can be displayed on `anchor` category and on quick search results pages only (set `Is Anchor` to `Yes` in the category).

Now you use an extension that replaces the native layered Magento, and also without the code of this extension it would be complicated to debug your problem.

To give an idea, I suggest you check this in the xml extension :

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
        // check this block with the custom one
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/> 
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: IS  Anchor to Yes is set in every category .

Comment: No, just the category of products that you want to include in layered navigation, the product should be visible

Comment: yes its set to Yes to those categories.

Comment: Reindex all and refresh your cache, if it doesn't work you have to check your xml as my answer